# Can't use layout as root view to do data binding via xml

Tags: android, layout, android-databinding

I have a main layout that looks like so.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/Titanium"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        style="@style/headline2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_size"
        android:text="BrickCity Style Guide"
        android:textColor="@color/Chalk"/>


     <include
         android:id="@+id/labelLayout"
         layout="@layout/simple_section_title"
         labelText="@{'Hello World'}"/>

</LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

And a secondary layout that i am trying to include and set its text from the main layout, that looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="labelText"
            type="String"/>
    </data>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/Chalk"
        android:paddingHorizontal="@dimen/margin_size"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/s3"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/s2"
        android:text="@{labelText}"
        style="@style/overline"/>

</layout>
```

Android studio seems to thing everything is ok, it builds and there are no xml errors in the ide.  But the app crashes with the error:

**Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class layout**

I have never done the xml data binding before so im not sure what if i am doing that part right, so i commented out the include from the main layout to see if the error went away, but it didn't.  It is complaining about my layout starting with

But everywhere i have read, it is nescisarry to do the data binding.

Anyone ever do this before.

Activity is just calling `setContentView(R.layout.main)` and extends `AppCompatActivity`

Answer (score 1):

Add `<data></data>` tag inside your layout since `layout` lag must be followed by `data` tag:

> Data binding layout files are slightly different and start with a root tag of layout **followed by a data element and a view root element**.

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<data>

</data>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/Titanium"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        style="@style/headline2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_size"
        android:text="BrickCity Style Guide"
        android:textColor="@color/Chalk"/>


     <include
         android:id="@+id/labelLayout"
         layout="@layout/simple_section_title"
         labelText="@{'Hello World'}"/>

</LinearLayout>

<layout>
```

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions